# Object instead of Map.Entry when consuming Stream

Tags: java, generics, java-stream

Given snippet:

```
Map map1 = new HashMap<>();
map1.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
});
```

Without declaring generic types I get a compilation errors generally saying that `entry` in `forEach` is an Object type and not a `Map.Entry`.

If I add generics (either `Object` or `?`), it compiles just fine:

```
Map<Object,Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
map2.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
});

Map<?,?> map3 = new HashMap<>();
map3.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
});
```

Same compilation error when calling other `Stream`'s API methods like `filter`, `map`, ...

Why missing generics makes compilation errors?

Comment: [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it).

Comment: I know about raw types. But generally my question is why compiler assumes that `entrySet()` returns `Set<Object>`, but `entrySet` method's is declared like this: `Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet();` which clearly states that it is a `Set<Map.Entry<...>>` and only typename of key and value are raw type.

Comment: The linked question contains the answer: *The type of a constructor, instance method, or non-static field of a raw type `C` that is not inherited from its superclasses or superinterfaces is the raw type that corresponds to the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to `C`*. In short, when you use a raw `Map`, the compiler erases all generic type information from the `Map` class.